# Caml Query Filter by FileType

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

What is missing in the below Query? Its fetches all the records from document Library?

```
//Specify the Caml Query
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /><Value Type='text'>msg</Value></Contains></Where></View>";

            ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `Query` node inside of the `View` node, and the `Where` inside of that `Query`:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml =
@"<View Scope='Recursive'>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type'/>
        <Value Type='text'>msg</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>";
```